# CryptHashData equivalent for C#?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I am trying to translate some existing C++ code to C#. I have some code which calls `CryptHashData` 3 times on the same `HCRYPTHASH`. The documentation says "This function and `CryptHashSessionKey` can be called multiple times to compute the hash of long or discontinuous data streams."

Which is what I want to achieve in C#. Unfortunately, `MD5.ComputeHash()` doesn't appear to have a way to build on the existing hash.

Am I missing something, is there a C# API that would achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate an instance of the hash class and use [`TransformBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx) and [`TransformFinalBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock.aspx):

```
byte[] part1 = //...
byte[] part2 = //...
byte[] part3 = //...
var hash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
hash.TransformBlock(part1, 0, part1.Length, null, 0);
hash.TransformBlock(part2, 0, part2.Length, null, 0);
hash.TransformFinalBlock(part3, 0, part3.Length);
byte[] res = hash.Hash;
```

Answer (score 0):

The cryptography functions in C# are limited. It's better to import CryptoAPI in C#.

```
[DllImport("Advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern Boolean CryptHashData (
    IntPtr hHash,
    Byte[] pbData,
    Int32 dwDataLen,
    Int32 dwFlags
);
```

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867087.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2007/11/23/p-invoking-cryptoapi-in-net-c-version.aspx) for more.